# How to create static CSRF token in php like facebook and Google?

Tags: php, security, session, token, csrf-protection

I am trying to build a CSRF protected web app in PHP. I am trying to keep a token in session for one time use for user as to protect their security. Now the problem is that when ever I refresh page or visit another page my token get changed. I don't want it to happen. I want to set single session token so user can access website without any problem of token mismatch. My codes for session are

```
<?php
function rand_csrf_string($length = 7) {
    $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['CSRF_TOKEN'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['CSRF_TOKEN'] = rand_csrf_string() ;
}

echo $_SESSION['CSRF_TOKEN'];
?>
```

Now when ever I refresh this session page, it is generating new token, I do not want token to get changed with every refresh or new page view. So can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Move `session_start()` out of the condition.

Comment: Just a note on your code (not your original problem) - you shouldn't use `rand` as it won't create you a secure random number (it is predictable). You should implement something using the function `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving **session_start();** to the top of your script will fix this problem for you. :)